# Convert all text from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa?

Tags: sed

My question is how can I convert all text from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa? That is to change the cases of all the letters. It has to be done with a `sed` replacement somehow.

Comment: `tr` would be more suitable than `sed`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a straight way in `sed`:

```
$ echo qWeRtY | sed -e 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
QwErTy
```

or a shorter way with GNU `sed`, working with any character for which a lowercase<->uppercase conversion exists in your locale:

```
$ echo qWeRtY | sed -E 's/([[:lower:]])|([[:upper:]])/\U\1\L\2/g'
QwErTy
```

if you can use another tools, like:

`perl` (limited to ASCII letters):

```
$ echo qWeRtY | perl -pe 'y/[a-z][A-Z]/[A-Z][a-z]/'
QwErTy
```

`perl` (more generally):

```
$ echo 'αΒγ' | perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/(\p{Ll})|(\p{Lu})/uc($1).lc($2)/ge'
ΑβΓ
```

Comment: Your second one assumes a GNU `sed` and alternate case in the input. Use `sed -re 's/([[:lower:]]?)([[:upper:]]?)/\U\1\L\2/g'` instead (still GNU specific). The first one only converts the 26 ASCII latin letters, while the second converts any letter recognised as such by your locale. The `tr` one only makes sense in ASCII locales. The `perl` one only works for ASCII latin letters.

Answer (score 18):

POSIXly, that can't be done with `sed` except by providing the complete set of letters you want to transliterate as [@cuonglm has shown](/a/136123).

It could be done with `tr` though, and that's what `tr` is for (transliterate):

```
tr '[:lower:][:upper:]' '[:upper:][:lower:]'
```

However, on Linux, it's got limitations. Of the 3 `tr` implementations commonly found on Linux-based systems:

- with GNU `tr`, that only works for single-byte character sets. For instance, on `Stéphane Chazelas` in UTF-8 locales, that gives `sTéPHANE cHAZELAS` instead of `sTÉPHANE cHAZELAS`. That's a known limitation of GNU `tr`.
- with `tr` from the heirloom toolchest, that doesn't work (you get `stéphane chazelas`).
- That's not the kind of thing busybox `tr` will do.

On FreeBSD that works OK though. You'd expect it to work OK in certified Unix systems as well.

---

The `bash` shell has a dedicated operator for that:

```
in=AbCdE
out=${in~~}
```

With `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
out=${in//(#b)(([[:lower:]])|([[:upper:]]))/${(U)match[2]}${(L)match[3]}}
```

Comment: So in desktop world only OSX does it? Why can't it work? Is it just the different implementations as it seems there is a constant offset in the hex value between the lower case version of the accented char and it's uppercase counterpart?

Comment: @illuminÉ, not sure what you mean by _desktop world_. AFAICS, the problem is with GNU, most Unices have "desktops". Apart from ASCII and some iso8859 charsets, I'm not aware that you can generalise the hex offset thing, and that wouldn't make sense with encodings like UTF-8. For instance in UTF-8, uppercase `ⴠ` (e2 b4 a0) is `Ⴠ` (e1 83 80); both `i` (69) and `ı` (c4 b1) have `I` (49) as uppercase (except in Turkish locales where `i` becomes `İ`). The reason it doesn't work with GNU `tr` is that GNU `tr` works with bytes and not characters.

Comment: I sort of meant mainstream but it doesn't make sense really so thanks for the heads up. I just looked at the French accented chars(and really just "é") and made very simplistic assumptions, forgetting again that it's about bytes. But the heirloom one? I'll go read that answer again!

Comment: @illuminÉ, for heirloom, it's a different issue, it seems it only supports only one occurrence of `[:lower:]` or `[:upper:]` (so the first one is ignored). Even in French, `œ -> Œ` is `c5 93 -> c5 92` in UTF-8 and `bd -> bc` in iso8859-15.

Answer (score 3):

If your main objective is to convert a file from lowerclass to upperclass,
why dont you use `tr` and `STDOUT` to convert your file:

```
$cat FILENAME | tr a-z A-Z > FILENAME2
```

Where `FILENAME` is your original file.
Where `FILENAME2` is your converted output file.

Comment: It didn't work with accented chars, like `é` for example (at least in my file).

Answer (score 2):

Though this has the same limitations already mentioned as the `tr` solution offered by Stéphane Chazelas, it is another way to do it:

```
{   echo QWERTYqwerty | dd conv=lcase
    echo QWERTYqwerty | dd conv=ucase 
} 2>/dev/null
```

#### OUTPUT

```
qwertyqwerty
QWERTYQWERTY
```

I dump `stderr` into `/dev/null` there because `dd` also provides statistics of all its operations on the `2` file descriptor. This can be useful depending on what you're doing, but wasn't for this demonstration. All of the other stuff you can do with `dd` still applies, for instance:

```
echo QWERTYqwerty | dd bs=1 cbs=6 conv=unblock,ucase 2>/dev/null
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
QWERTY
QWERTY
```

Comment: It doesn't swap the case though (as in `aBc` is not converted to `AbC`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - true, but unless I've misunderstood, that wasn't the question, was it?

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`:

```
awk '{print tolower($0)}' file.txt | tee file.txt
```

Comment: you sure this is going to work? `>file.txt` would start off by truncating the file

Comment: Then you've obviously not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

`ruby` has a string method for that, similar usage from command line like `perl`

```
$ echo 'qWeRtY' | ruby -pe '$_.swapcase!'
QwErTy
```

See also [ruby-doc Encoding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Encoding.html)

```
$ ruby -e 'puts Encoding.default_external'
UTF-8
$ echo 'αΒγ'  | ruby -pe '$_.swapcase!'
ΑβΓ
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep simple thing simple. The filter designed to translate characters is `tr`.

```
echo 1ude1UDE | tr [:upper:][:lower:] [:lower:][:upper:]
```

Comment: That's a broken (because of the missing quotes around the globbing operators) version of [an answer already given 2 years earlier](/a/136132)